# How can I prevent the user to put invalid data and how can I compare two data in spring boot mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, jpa

I am sorry for not bein more specific in the title. Let me explain the situation.

I have two tables that have @OneToOne mapping.(Student,Class) In the application I have to assign a student to a class which I can do that by giving the class id. The problem is my application returns two exception which I cannot think of solving.

1. when I enter a non-exist class id it returns `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`
2. When I enter a non `int` value as class id it gives me typeMismatch exception

How can I solve my problems ?

Class entity

```
  @Entity(name = "class")
    @Table(name = "class")
    public class Clazz {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    private Subject subject;

   @OneToOne
    private Teacher teacher;
```

Student entity

```
Entity(name = "student")
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String first_name;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String last_name;

    @OneToOne
    private Clazz clazz;
    
    //getter setter
```

TypeMismatch exception

```
 Field error in object 'student' on field 'clazz.id': rejected value [asdasdasd]; codes [typeMismatch.student.clazz.id,typeMismatch.clazz.id,typeMismatch.id,typeMismatch.int,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [student.clazz.id,clazz.id]; arguments []; default message [clazz.id]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'clazz.id'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "asdasdasd"]]
```

SqlException

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`firsthelloacademy`.`student`, CONSTRAINT `FKq44plaaui3mcolfeasdjnsg34` FOREIGN KEY (`clazz_id`) REFERENCES `class` (`id`))
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    private ClazzService clazzService;

    @GetMapping("/showStudent")
    public String showStudents(Model model){

        //call dao method to get the data

        List<Student> studentList = studentService.loadStudents();

        model.addAttribute("students",studentList);

        return "student-list";

    }

    @GetMapping("/showAddStudentPage")
    public String addStudent(Model model) {

        Student student = new Student();

        model.addAttribute("student",student);

        return "add-student";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save-student")
    public String saveStudent(Student student, Model model, Clazz clazz) {

        List<Clazz> clazzList = clazzService.loadClazzes();

        model.addAttribute("clazzes",clazzList);

        //write the logic to save the data(studentDTO) to the database
        //do a condition check
        //if the user does have a id -> do a update
        //if the user doesn't have an id then do a insert

        if(student.getFirst_name().equals("") || student.getLast_name().equals("") || student.getClazz().getId() == 0 ) {

            model.addAttribute("error", "Invalid Student credintials");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("error basarili");

            return "add-student";

        }

        /*Problem starts here

       if(clazz.getId() != student.getClazz().getId()){

            model.addAttribute("clazzError","Class ID does not match");

            return "add-student";

        }

       And ends here  */
        
                
            System.out.println("ikinci kisma gidiyor");
            if(student.getId() == 0) {

                //insert a new record
                studentService.saveStudent(student);

            }else {

                //do an update
                studentService.update(student);

            }

            System.out.println(student);

            return "redirect:/showStudent";
    }

    @GetMapping("/updateStudent")
    public String updateStudent(@RequestParam("id") int id, Model model) {

        //give the user object who clicked on the update link
        System.out.println("looking for the student having id : " + id);

        Student theStudent = studentService.getStudent(id);
        System.out.println(theStudent);

        //setting the student information
        model.addAttribute("student", theStudent);

        return "add-student";
    }

    @GetMapping("/deleteStudent")
    public String deleteStudent(@RequestParam("id") int id) {

        //capture the id of the student whom you are trying to delete
        //once captured the id do a service call to delete the student

        studentService.deleteStudent(id);

        return "redirect:/showStudent";

    }
}
```

add-student.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<jsp:useBean id="student" class="com.firstHelloWorld.firstHelloAcademy.api.Student" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my-style-sheet.css">
</head>
<body>

<div align="center">

    <h2>Add Student</h2>

    <form:form action="save-student" modelAttribute="student" method="POST">

        <form:hidden path="id"/>

        <label>First Name : </label>
        <form:input path="first_name"/>

        <br>

        <label>Last Name : </label>
        <form:input path="last_name"/>

        <br>

        <label>Class ID : </label>
        <form:input path="clazz.id"/>

        <br>

         <p><b><span style="color:red">${error}</span></b></p>

         <br>

         <p><b><span style="color:red">${clazzError}</span></b></p>

         <input type="submit" value="Submit">

     </form:form>
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring JSR-303 Validators. Controllers can have validator injected which can validate inputs.

```
`@Controller
public class MyController {
    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(new InputValidator());
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/foo", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void processFoo(@Valid Foo foo) { ... }
    
}
 try {
        intValue = Integer.parseInt(string);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Input String cannot be parsed to Integer.");
    }
    return false;
```

`
You can specify a property file which holds key value pair for error msg and can return the error from controllers.
For more details https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch05s07.html

Comment: Hey Ashish, I tried it out and it works fine for now thank you !